# mciSendstring ¿system.nullreferenceexception?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una clase con este código:

```
class Mp3Player
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    public string returnData;
    private string command;

    public void Open(string file)
    {
        Close();
        command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        command = "close MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        command = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        command = "stop MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        Close();
    }

    public bool IsPlaying()
    {
        command = "status MyMp3 mode";
        mciSendString(command, returnData, 128, 0);

        string estado = "playing";
        if (returnData.Contains(estado))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Es para reproducir un archivo mp3 con la dll "winmm.dll", he visto varios ejemplos de código
y he tomado solo lo que a mi me interesa que son los métodos más básicos.

Todos los métodos me funcionan excepto el "IsPlaying()" que me da error ¿porque?
al parecer devuelve null, pero he leído como 50 veces la documentación y supuestamente está bien.

He probado de todo y no logro que me devuelva el estado.

Comment: ¿La variable `null` es `returnData`?

Comment: No la variable returnData en teoría debería devolver un string con "playing" o "stop" u otros pero no devuelve nada(null), entonces cuando hago la búsqueda returnData.Contains(estado) da la exception.

Comment: Mi pregunta es si la excepción se da justo en el método `mciSendString` o es en la línea de `returnData.Contains(estado)`.

Comment: Es en la linea returnData.Contains(estado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que estoy leyendo [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757161(v%3Dvs.85)), el segundo parámetro del método `mciSendString` debe ser un *buffer* donde se recibirá la información.

> Pointer to a buffer that receives return information. If no return information is needed, this parameter can be **NULL**.

En tu caso, estás llamando al método con tu variable `returnData`, pero `returnData` es `null`, nunca la inicializas. Al pasarle un `null` como segundo parámetro, la función `mciSendString` lo ignora.
Es decir, una vez llamado el método, tu variable `returnData` sigue siendo `null`.
Por ello, la línea `returnData.Contains(estado)` lanza la `NullPointerException`.

Se solucionaría simplemente inicializando `returnData` con un *string* vacío.

```
class Mp3Player
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    public string returnData = string.Empty;
    private string command;

    // ...

    public bool IsPlaying()
    {
        command = "status MyMp3 mode";
        mciSendString(command, returnData, 128, 0);

        string estado = "playing";

        return returnData.Contains(estado);
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias,ya no me salta la excepción aunque sigue sin devolverme un información, voy a seguir probando e investigando.